# Permission Denied error for Vagrant

Tags: permissions, vagrant

I made the mistake of once running "sudo vagrant up" and now whenever I run "vagrant up" it gives me the following error

```
==> default: Running cleanup tasks for 'chef_solo' provisioner...
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:492:in `initialize':   P Permission denied - /Users/mkv/.vagrant.d/data/lock.fpcollision.lock (Errno::EACCES)
```

I've tried deleting the .vagrant folder and also the Cheffile but I always get the same error.

What can I do to sort this out?

Comment: delete `/Users/mkv/.vagrant.d/data/lock.fpcollision.lock` and run `vagrant up` again. Second, find any files are owned by root under /Users/mkv, include hide files. if found, change it back to your own user account.

Comment: Good news, then I answer it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is related with permission which you accidentally run the application with root.

Follow the steps:

1. Delete `/Users/mkv/.vagrant.d/data/lock.fpcollision.lock` and run `vagrant up` again.
2. Find any files are owned by root under /Users/mkv, include hide files. if found, change it back to your own user account.

You can run below command to find out files owned by root

```
  find /Users/mkv -type f -user root -print
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who wonder how to change a user to your current one, using find command:

```
sudo find ~/.vagrant.d/data/lock.fpcollision.lock -type f -user root -exec chown $USER {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked! I ran `sudo vagrant up` which started to cause all these issues.

Comment: Way to respond almost a year and a half later ;)

Comment: @theGreenCabbage It was really hard to hold me that long.. I've almost slipped to respond in few minutes, but then I'd to tell myself "You are stronger than this. Good things take time". And I wait.. Till this day.